# Iterate over a list and subtract 1 subsequently and pop in python

Tags: python

I want to iterate over a list first pop the last element and then subtract 1 from all values and then repeat. i want to save the popped element in a new list.

input- [5 9 5 7]

output- [7 4 7 2]

Explanation-

first we pop 7 and then the list remains 5,9,5 and then we subtract 1 from remaining 3 numbers and then pop 4 because(5-1) then similarly forward. and on the number being 0 we don't subtract forward the element of array should not go in minus.

i tried coding it but couldn't get the logic-

```
n = int(input())
arr = sorted(list(int(num) for num in input().strip().split()))[:n]
result = []
for j in range(1,n):
     a=arr.pop()
     for i in range(1,n):
        if(arr[i] > i):
           arr[i] = arr[i] - 1
        else:
           arr[i] = 0
```

Comment: Do you really have to do it like that? You could just take the last item, then the previous one minus 1, the previous minus 2 and so on - that would also be more efficient.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I thought of it as i am a newbie in programming. I could not code the same. can you give me a snippet.

Comment: What I mean is: is that some homework, and you are asked to implement it the way you described (pop, subtract one to all remaining items, repeat) or do you just want the expected output, whatever method you use, in which case there are simpler and more efficient ways to get it.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille No it is not a homework, I just want to code it efficiently I tried the pop method the error comes out to be "list index out of range" when iterating and poping i know I can't pop and iterate at the same time and also i want to iterate it till arr[i] > i so that the number doesn't comes in minus. can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a more Pythonic one liner:

```
out_arr = [in_arr[i] + (i+1) for i in range(-1, -1*len(in_arr)-1, -1)] # [7, 4, 7, 2]
```

This relies on the observation that you decrement the elements (pointed out by @Thierry Lathuille). In my answer, I use the faster list comprehension to generate the output list. This explains what the for loop does: `for i in range(start_index=-1, on_over_stop_index=-5, step_size=-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
l=[5,9,5,7]
result= []

for i in range(0,len(l)): 
    last_elem = l.pop() 
    result.append(last_elem) 
    l = [i-1 for i in l]
print(result)
```

Comment: I Don't, want the new elements of the array to go in minus i want to stop at 0 when the elements of array become 0. Please read my whole question.

Comment: @AryanJha She is subtracting 1 from older elements only, not from new elements. I think you haven't understood the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a new list, a good way is to use a list comprehension.

If you want to iterate on a list and use the indices of the items, use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) that will provide the index of the item and the item on each iteration. It's better and cleaner than iterating on the indices.

To iterate on a list in reverse order, use [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed).

So, combining all of this, a nice, short and pythonic solution could be:

```
data = [5, 9, 5, 7]

out = [item - index for index, item in enumerate(reversed(data))]

print(out)
# [7, 4, 7, 2]
```

---

I did some timings to test this solution vs using indices (and added a third solution using slicing with `[::1]`)

```
data = [100] * 1000000


def with_indices(in_arr):
    return [in_arr[i] + (i+1) for i in range(-1, -1*len(in_arr)-1, -1)]

def with_reversed(data):
    return [item - index for index, item in enumerate(reversed(data))]

def with_slice(data):
    return [item - index for index, item in enumerate(data[::-1])]

%timeit with_indices(data)
%timeit with_reversed(data)
%timeit with_slice(data)
```

Output:

```
204 ms ± 3.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
141 ms ± 322 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
156 ms ± 398 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Using `reversed` and `enumerate` is always about 30% faster than using indices (even for small lists of 10 items). Slicing is a bit slower than using `reversed` - I suppose that this is due to the creation of the reversed list, while `reversed` just iterates on the original.

Answer (score -2):

You can

- use the reversed iterator to create the reversed list,
- then enumerate on top of that to find which index you're at,
- then append the the element value subtracted by the index to accomplish what you want

Code:

```
mylist = [5,9,5,7]
output = []
for idx, elem in FUNCTION1(FUNCTION2(mylist)):
  print (f'{idx} {elem}')
  output.append(SUBTRACTION HERE)
print(output)
```

Comment: how to check for the condition in "SUBTRACTION HERE"? As i am passing a sorted list so i want itterate it till A[i] >i

Comment: The "for" loop will ensure that you iterate over all the elements once.  If you use the reversed iterator, it will effectively stop at 0 (ie checking for i>=0 in the C language)

The subtraction is as @Thierry-lathuille is describing.  eg.

REVERSED: 

index 0: 7-0 = 7

index 1: 5-1 = 4

index 2: 9-2 = 7

index 3: 5-3 = 2